# Redis 2.8 Memory efficiency make test error

Tags: redis, centos6.4

I'm attempting to install Redis 2.8 but when I ran `make test`, it threw out an error for this:

> *** [err]: Memory efficiency with values in range 16384 in tests/unit/memefficiency.tcl Expected condition '$efficiency >=
>   $expected_min_efficiency' to be true (0.83004811885510699 >= 0.90)

What does this mean for the server that I'm installing this on? It used to work with Redis 2.6

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you didn't use an efficient `malloc` implementation. Did you use `make USE_TCMALLOC=yes`? (Or you can just [ignore the error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/RIk2Ic5H9QY/z3bbd4kiK0kJ) if you don't particularly care about memory efficiency.)

Comment: I used Redis 2.8 default which is jemalloc.. isn't that better for fragmentation issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a false positive.

Redis 2.8.1 fixed it.
https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.8/00-RELEASENOTES

Thanks!